# why is my code only printing the first line of cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

So I am learning how to use cmd from python and tried to do this:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE,  encoding = 
'utf8', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('dir c:\\')
print(stdout)
```

This apparently does not work as this is what i recieve:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>More?

WHy only one line and not what was commanded?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028246/9200529) suggests a better approach to communicating with the shell on windows:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output('cmd /k dir c:\\', shell = True)
```